# Extract data from google chart

Tags: screen-scraping, web-crawler, google-visualization

I am looking for a way to extract data from a chart displayed on Google's transparency report. 
http://www.google.com/transparencyreport/traffic/

The chart is shown in flash and displays traffic by country and product.

Is there a possible way to programmatically get the data shown ?

Comment: Just to get the element from the dom tree and check the argument if it contains any reference to a data request. It seems to show something but is not readable. Are you familiar with such a problem ?

Comment: When you select a country it sends a request that returns json data. So you would need to construct the requests and parse the data.